# Regarding gekommen

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm totally jumping into German so due apologies — I'm trying to figure out how *gekommen* works:

(1) *Die Frage ist in Vergessenheit.*

versus

(2) *Die Frage ist in Vergessenheit gekommen.*

What's the difference here? Is *gekommen* introducing a change of tense?

Comment: "Ist in Vergenssenheit gekommen" literally means "has *come* into oblivion", although most Germans would say "Ist in Vergessenheit *geraten*".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- > Die Frage ist in Vergessenheit.
  >   The question **is** forgotten.

  This describes a state in the present. The tense of the German sentence is *Präsens* (very close related, but not equal to English *present tense*). The verb *"ist"* (a form of *"sein" = "to be"*) is used as a full verb here.
- > Die Frage ist in Vergessenheit gekommen.
  >   The question **became** forgotten.

  This describes a transition that happened in the past. The tense of the German sentence is *Perfekt* (related to English *past tense*). The Verb *"ist"* is here used as an auxiliary verb. It has no semantic function here, it is needed only for grammatical reasons, to build the tense *Perfekt*. The full verb is *"gekommen"*, this is a form of *"kommen"* (normally *"to come"*, but here, in this context: *"to become"*). In *Präsens* you don't need the auxiliary verb, and the full verb goes to position 2 (it also changes its form). So you get:

  > Die Frage kommt in Vergessenheit.
  >   The question becomes forgotten.

But *"gekommen"* is second choice here. There is an idiomatic phrase in German for *"becoming forgotten":*

> Die Frage ist in Vergessenheit **geraten.** (Tense: *Perfekt*)
>   Die Frage **gerät** in Vergessenheit. (Tense: *Präsens*)

In German you use *"Vergessenheit"* like a hidden place where questions, memories and other stuff moves. You don't do this in English. In English you use the past participle of the verb *to forget* to describe the same fact.

Comment: "Die Frage ist in Vergessenheit", ohne weiteres Verb, habe ich noch nie gehört und ich würde auf ein Verb warten, wenn ich es höre.

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt, aber andererseits ist es nicht völlig ungrammatisch. Wenn jemand ein Gedicht schreibt (über eine Frage?!) könnte das dann schon so drinnen stehen.

Comment: Es ist nicht ungrammatisch, aber einem Neulerner empfiehlt man keine Idiomatik, die kein Muttersprachler nutzt, ohne Warnung, nur weil es jemand sagen/verstehen könnte. Gerade weil es nicht ungrammatisch ist würde ich von der Formulierung abraten.

Answer (score 1):

Hardly any native or fluent speaker would say

> Die Frage ist in Vergessenheit.

German speakers would rather say:

> Die Frage ist in Vergessenheit geraten.

*... ist in Vergessenheit geraten* is a fixed construction, meaning *... has become forgotten* (literally: *has come into oblivion* or *has come to be forgotten*).

You *could* say:

> Die Frage ist in Vergessenheit gekommen.

but it would sound unusual. The construction *in ... gekommen* is generally not used with *Vergessenheit*. But you can say:

> Diese Röcke sind in Mode gekommen

Meaning *these skirts have become fashionable* or, more literally, *these skirts have come to be in fashion*.

Comment: I agree. Number (1) is not correct, or in any case not idiomatic.